# (WORKINGS SHOWN) Simple statistical hypothesis question

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

A drug company claims that 75% of patients suffering from depression recover when treated with a new drug. A doctor believes that the claim is not true and thr percentage who will recover is lower than 75%.

1)Set up the null and alternative hypothesis.
MY ANSWER:

Let $p$ be the percent of patients who will recover.

Let $\hat p$ be the sample percentage of patients who will recover

The hypotheses: $H_O$: $p=0.75$, $H_\alpha$: $p<0.75$

---

2) The doctor selects a random sample of 225 patients and uses the following rule:

If the sample shows that more than 162 patients recovered, conclude that the claim is acceptable. Otherwise conclude that the claim is not acceptable.

Find the probability of a Type 1 error.

MY ANSWER:

We conclude that the doctor's claim is true when we reject $H_o$.

Let $X$ be the number of patients in the sample who recover.

Reject $H_o$ if X>162 (reject $H_o$ if $X/n > 162/225$). Hence reject $H_o$ if $\hat p > 162/225 = 0.72$. The probability of a Type 1 error is:

$\begin{split}\alpha &= P(\text{reject $H_o$ when $H_o$ true})
\\ &= P(\hat p>0.72\text{ when }p=0.75)
\\ &=P\left(\frac{\hat p-p}{\sqrt {pq/n}} > \frac{0.72 -0.75}{\sqrt{(0.75)(0.25)/225}}\right)
\\ &=P(Z> - 1247.08)
\\&=\ldots
\end{split}$

I am trying to solve this question and that is my process work. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: $Z<$ , not greater than, because you are testing the hypothesis against the left tail, and the calculation should give $-1.0392304845413263761164678049035...$ $$\alpha=P(Z <-1.0392)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\alpha &= \mathbb{P}(\hat{p} < 0.72 |p = 0.75)\\ &= \Phi\left( \frac{0.72-0.75}{\sqrt{0.25(1-0.25)/225}} \right)\\ &= \Phi(-1.04)\\ &= 1- \Phi(1.04)\\ &=1 - 0.85\\ &= 0.15
\end{align}